# iOS Books app often opens at a previous page

Tags: books, ipados

When I open Books to continue reading a book it often opens to an earlier page than the one I was before, sometimes several chapters back. The same happens when I do a lookup and then jump back to continue reading. I only use Books on the iPad so it doesn't seem to be a syncing issue.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does it only happen with specific books or with all of them?